# KDE Dolphin stopped using folder icon for regular folders

Tags: kde, dolphin

How do I make Dolphin use folder icons for regular folders? Icons for all the special folders—Downloads, Pictures, Music—work fine.

This affects all installed themes, so this is not some kind of theme corruption.

Here's how it looks—foobar is a regular folder:

[image: dolphin screenshot with broken folder icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open System Settings
2. Go to Personalization > Applications > File Associations
3. Select the inode/directory file type in "Known Types" list
4. Change the icon to inode-directory or whatever you want by clicking a big button on "General" tab
5. Click Apply
6. Refresh Dolphin by pressing the F5 key

Comment: There is no "System Settings"